# Add given relative path ot another path in a string with Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I've a string, with some relative paths inside, like the following for example:

```
<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>..\..\..\..\..\..\external\gmock\gmock-1.7.0\include;..\..\..\..\..\..\external\gmock\gmock-1.7.0\gtest\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
```

And I want to only add `..\..\` for each path.

I can do that with `replace` method, but the problem here is that the number of "up step" is not fixed (dependending of the string I want to replace).

If I try to just replace `..\` with something like `..\..\..\` my script replace each occurence he found. So I have the following at final result `..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\`.

So how I can only add 2 "up step" to each path in this string in Python 3.

The desired result is:

```
<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\external\gmock\gmock-1.7.0\include;..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\external\gmock\gmock-1.7.0\gtest\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
```

Comment: post the desired result

Comment: if your path always start by `/external` you can use as to `replace('/external', '/../../external')` ...?

Comment: Hmm.. what if you replace each `..\ ` with `.+.\.+.\ `. Then at the end, remove all `+` from the string. Just something to get you thinking outside the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways but this should work.

```
a = 'AdditionalIncludeDirectories>..\..\..\..\..\..\external\gmock\gmock-1.7.0\include;..\..\..\..\..\..\external\gmock\gmock-1.7.0\gtest\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>'  
b = re.search('>(.*)<', a)## Get paths str position
paths_str = a[b.start() + 1:b.end() - 1]## paths_str
paths = paths_str.split(';')
full_paths = ['..\..\{0}'.format(path) for path in paths]## adding up dirs
full = '{0}>{1}<;{2}'.format(a[:b.start()], ';'.join(full_paths), 
a[b.end():])## Combining together.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex substitution of the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module:

```
>>> s = '..\..\..\..\..\..\external\gmock\...;..\..\..\..\..\..\external...'
>>> import re
>>> print(re.sub(r'(\.\.\\)+', r"..\\..\\", s))
..\..\external\gmock\...;..\..\external...
```